# DEFOLD make android bundle for x86 Emulator

Tags: android, apk, emulation, defold

Defold bundle by default creates armv7-android ABIS APK. Which when installed on an x86 emulator gives the following error

> [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]

Can't seem to find a way to create APK from defold which will run with x86 architecture.

Comment: Defold does not currently build APKs that you can run for the x86 emulator. This is actually the first time anyone has asked about this as far as I can remember.

Comment: What emulator did you use? Ihaven't tried https://www.bluestacks.com/ myself, but it was recommended on the [Defold forums](https://forum.defold.com/t/hi-i-just-want-to-run-my-game-on-android-emulator/2318/2)